# How to change the button size in the dialog jQuery

Tags: button, size

I have the following jQuery dialog. How can I change the button size of the two buttons? So they won't be underneath each other, but next to each other.

Here is my code

```
function ApplyJQueryUI() {
       $("#<%= callForwardingAlwaysOption.ClientID %>").buttonset();

       $("#callForwardingAlwaysDialog").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "fade",
            closeOnEscape: false,
            hide: "fade",
            buttons: {
                "> Ok": function () {
                    $("#<%= callForwardingAlwaysButton.ClientID %>").click();                        
                },
                "> Annuleren": function () {
                    $("#<%= callForwardingAlwaysOption.ClientID %>_0").attr("checked", "checked");
                    $("#<%= callForwardingAlwaysOption.ClientID %>").buttonset("refresh");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
       });
        $('#callForwardingAlwaysDialog').keypress(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
                    $("#<%= callForwardingAlwaysButton.ClientID %>").click(); 
                }
        });

        $("#callForwardingAlwaysDialog").parent().appendTo($("#<%= callForwardingAlwaysUpdatePanel.ClientID %>:first"));

          if (isPostBack){ 
          $(dialogInstance).dialog("close");
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a little bit of CSS, all you need to do is reduce the font size:

```
#dialog .ui-button-text {
font-size: 10px; /* Or whatever smaller value works for you. */
}
```

You can also drop the padding:

```
#dialog .ui-button-text {
font-size: 10px;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px; /* Or whatever makes it small enough. */
}
```

Comment: first off all thnx, I addedthe last option to the base.css

however where do i need to call the css in the dialog becuase there isn't changed anything?? i olso changed the '#' to a dott just to trye ( both didn't change anything)

Comment: Please upvote the answer if you find it related so that it would be helpful for the community.